# Loading RIA services at runtime using PRISM in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria, prism-4

I am trying to create a modular Silverlight 4.0 application, where the modules are configured using the XAML module catalog.

Some of the modules are RIA Services. Now, the XAML module catalog requires that the modules should be Silverlight Applications and not class libraries. It seems that server side RIA library can be referred from client side only if the client assembly is a class library. A Silverlight application can only be linked to RIA service hosted in a web project.

A workaround would be to use the RIA service project, containing the client and server side assemblies, then add another Silverlight application which refers to the client assembly, and define that application as PRISM module.

But I am assuming there must be a better way. Any second thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer in Silverlight forum:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/219603/524600.aspx#524600